# add datetime.timedelta() to a python mysql query

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I want to add the following code which has datetime variable to a mysl query :

```
tb1.primeday > (datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=Days))
```

to this query:

```
q = """
    SELECT tb1.id
    FROM tb1
    join tb3 ON tb3.id= tb1.csid
    """
```

I have tried this, but does not work:

```
q = """
    SELECT tb1.id
    FROM tb1
    join tb3 ON tb3.id= tb1.csid
    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, tb1.primeday, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, 
    {},tb3.Days))
    """.format(datetime.now().date())
```

The format of `tb1.primeday` is something like:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Do you have idea where is the problem or what's the best solution?

Comment: I would suggest using MySQL's built in `CURDATE()` (date) or `NOW()` (datetime) function, rather than passing your query Python's `datime.now()`. On a side note, you should be using a Python module that allows you to create a prepared (parameterized) statement, where you do not have to pass a value directly into a query string, but rather you create the prepared query with placeholders, and then pass the values to the database. This guards against things like an SQL injection (both malicious and accidental).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes I thought about this solution before. Something like q += `'WHERE tb1.primeday > {}-{}.format(NOW(), timedelta(days=Days)'`, however my problem is *Days* which is a field in each row of tables and changes so it's something which makes it very confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you print the value of `q` you can see something like this:

```
>>> print(q)

    SELECT tb1.id
    FROM tb1
    join tb3 ON tb3.id= tb1.csid
    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, tb1.primeday, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,
    2019-08-24,tb3.Days))
```

As I remember, any literal date should be quoted. So you should replace `{}` with `'{}'`.

```
q = """
    SELECT tb1.id
    FROM tb1
    join tb3 ON tb3.id= tb1.csid
    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, tb1.primeday, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, 
    '{}',tb3.Days))
    """.format(datetime.now().date())
```

The result will be

```
    SELECT tb1.id
    FROM tb1
    join tb3 ON tb3.id= tb1.csid
    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, tb1.primeday, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,
    '2019-08-24',tb3.Days))
```

According to the documentation, this should work correctly.

## Enhancement

(thanks to the author of the first comment)

On the other hand, if the clock on the MySQL server and on your computer are synchronized, you can replace the creation of the literal date with the call of DATE(NOW())

```
q = """
    SELECT tb1.id
    FROM tb1
    join tb3 ON tb3.id= tb1.csid
    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, tb1.primeday, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, 
    DATE(NOW()),tb3.Days))
    """
```